# Need a alternative to Appium Inspector to view xpath of ios app elements, appium inspector is not getting refreshed

Tags: xpath

Need a alternative to Appium Inspector to view xpath of ios app elements, appium inspector is not getting refreshed ,so that i need to restart the inspector every time to work ,and when connecting its very slow , kindly suggest me alternative .

Comment: What do you mean by 'not getting refreshed'? Did you try to refresh it using the button or you expect it to refresh automatically while you do something on the device? There are some other tools but under the hood  they still use WDA so I don't think you'll get better performance than the original Inspector

Comment: i mean not getting refreshed when i hit the refresh button in appium inspector ,its not getting refreshed ,so i need to restart the session

Comment: can you please suggest the other tools you know ?

Comment: For iOS you can use Xcode's `Accessibility Inspector`, you can try [online](https://inspector.appiumpro.com) version of Appium inspector. If you have access to the app code you can also debug it through Xcode and get the elements hierarchy. Another tool you can try out is [Katalon](https://katalon.com). In general I haven't encountered such problem except on apps with huuge webviews so I would also advise you update to the latest Appium version.

Comment: thanks let me try katalon